# Classes for AppSync are not automatically created

Tags: android, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I have been trying out the AppSync tutorial given by AWS at this link [https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-mobile-android-notes-tutorial/blob/master/tutorial/data.md] I've been trying to see if I could use AppSync with its GraphQL APIs for one of my school projects.

I've made it to the 'Add serverless backend' section and it looks like some classes were not automatically generated, e.g GetNoteQuery, DeleteNoteInput...... Attached is a picture of my code [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhUbx.png)